# web crawler does not retrive title and description

Tags: node.js, web, web-crawler

i want to make simple web crawler in nodejs that will extract the tittle and description from URL that will be visisted by login member ..first member will login then if he want to crawl..this will be done by "createdby" columnid 
here is my code ,
dal/url.js:

```
   var mysql = require('mysql-libmysqlclient');
      var cheerio = require('cheerio');
      var async = require('async');
      var db = require('mysql');
      var generator = require('../bal/urlgenerator');
      var crawler = require('../bal/url');

      var cutil = require('../util/crawler_utils');              
      var request = require('request');
      var fs = require("fs");

      var path = require("path");
      var domain = "http://www.pin.tl/" ;


      var configs = fs.readFileSync(path.resolve(__dirname, "../config.json"));
      if (configs) {
       configs = JSON.parse(configs.toString());
         }
     else {
     throw error;
       }

       exports.insert = function (req,res) {

       var surl = generator.generateURL().toString();

       db.db_connect(function (err, con) {
       if (err) {
        throw err;
        }

       else {

       var custom = req.body.curl;
       if(!custom=="")
       {
       var insertQry = "INSERT INTO URL(idURL, URL, Name, ShortURL, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, Code, idCategoryURL, IP) values(" +
                "uuid(),'" + req.body.url + "', '' , '"+ domain+custom +"', '"+req.params.userid+"', Now(), '"+custom+"', '15e90e46-ed13-11e2-8bca-74867a028220', '"+req.connection.remoteAddress+"')";
         console.log(insertQry)
         con.query(insertQry, function (err, msg) {
         if (err) {

          throw err;
          } else {
          console.log("Data successfully inserted");

          }

          });
           }

          else {
        var insertQry = "INSERT INTO URL(idURL, URL, Name, ShortURL, CreatedBy, CreatedDate, Code, idCategoryURL, IP) values(" +
                "uuid(),'" + req.body.url + "', '' , '"+ domain+surl +"', '"+req.params.userid+"', Now(), '"+surl+"', '15e90e46-ed13-11e2-8bca-74867a028220', '"+req.connection.remoteAddress+"')";
         console.log(insertQry)
        con.query(insertQry, function (err, msg) {
        if (err) {
        throw  err;
        } else {
        console.log("Data successfully inserted");
          res.send(domain+surl);
         res.send(req.body.FullName);
          }

          });
          }

          }
         });
        }

      exports.selectAll = function (req, res) {
      db.db_connect(function (err, con) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    else {

      var select ="select * from URL where CreatedBy = '"+req.params.id+"'";
      con.query(select, function (err, msg) {
      if (err) {
     throw  err;
        }
            else {
       console.log("Select All from URL");
       msg.fetchAll(function(err, rows){

        if(err){
        throw err;
        }

         else{
        res.json(rows);

       }
       Crawler = function(){
       var self = this;
       this.conn = db.createConnection(config.get('db'));
       this.indexed = 0;
        this._url = select;
       console.log(select);
       this.url = select;
       this.crawl = function(cb){
        this.conn.query('SELECT * FROM `queue` LIMIT 0,1',function(e,result){
       self.url = result.length > 0 ? result[0].url : select;
       request(self.url,function(e,res,body){
        if(result.length > 0){
        self.conn.query('DELETE FROM `queue` WHERE `id` = ?',[result[0].id],function(){
        cb();
        });
         }
        else {
        cb();
        }
        if(!e && res.statusCode === 200){
        self.getInfo(body,result.length > 0 ? result[0].from : '');
       }
       else {
       console.log('Error requesting page %s',self.url);
       }
       self._url = self.url;
        });
       });
       };
      this.getInfo = function(html,from){
       var $ = cheerio.load(html);
       var title = $('head title').text();
       var keywords = $('head meta[name=keywords]').attr('content');
       var desc = $('head meta[name=description]').attr('content');
      var links = $('a');
       console.log('Crawling "%s" | %s',title,this.url);
        async.map(links.map(function(){
        var href = $(this).attr('href');
        if(href && href != self._url && !(/^#(\w)+/.test(href)) && !cutil.imageRegexp.test(href)){
        if(cutil.isExternal(href)){
                                        return 'INSERT INTO `queue` SET `id` = ``\''+cutil.id()+'\', `url` = '+self.conn.escape(href)+', `from` = '+self.conn.escape(from);
          }
         else {
         return 'INSERT INTO `queue` SET `id` = \''+cutil.id()+'\', `url` = '+self.conn.escape(cutil.resolveRelativeURL(href,self._url))+', `from` = '+self.conn.escape(from);
       }
        }
        return false;
         }).filter(function(el){
        return !!el;
        })
         ,this.conn.query.bind(this.conn),function(e,result){
        if(e){
        console.log('Error writing queue.');
        console.log(e);
         }
          });
         this.conn.query('INSERT INTO `URL` SET ?',{
        id:cutil.id(),
        url:this.url,
        from:from,
        title:title,
        keywords:keywords || '',
       desc:desc || ''
       },function(e){
       if(e){
       console.log('Error indexing page %s',self.url);
        console.log(e);
        }
        else {
       console.log('Successfully indexed page %s',self.url);
       self.indexed++;
       }
       });
       };
       };
       });

      }

      });

       }


       });

       }
```